# Add combo box items from other class to main form in Visual Studio C# forms?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I have a class that runs SQL query and add items to combo box by calling my main form combo box. But after I run my program my combo box is not populated.

Here is my main form code.

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.getPrinID();
}
```

Here is my C# class code

```
public void getPrinID()
{
    main = new frmMain();

    con.Open();

    sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(ClassID)) AS ClassID FROM ProductClass", con);
    dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        main.cmbPrin.Items.Add(row["ClassID"].ToString());
    }

    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: You should return list of items from the `getPrintID` method. call that method from the form and populate the combobox using those items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

despite being a bad solution, to get this done you have to pass the form reference, not create a new one.

pass `this` as a parameter to the function `getPrinID()`.

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.getPrinID(this);
}
```

set `frmMain` as expected parameter to the function.

```
public void getPrinID(frmMain main)
{
    con.Open();

    sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(ClassID)) AS ClassID FROM ProductClass", con);
    dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        main.cmbPrin.Items.Add(row["ClassID"].ToString());
    }

    con.Close();
}
```

remember that the combobox `cmbPrin` access level must be set to public.

Comment: Can I know how I can optimize my code?. Btw Thank you very much.

Comment: a good solution is call `getPrinID` which should return of a list of whateveer you want and fill the combobox in the main form using those values.